# Javascript Hide Input Field based on Select change TEXT not VALUE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list (select) populated from SQL. This is dynamic so can change at any time. I need to hide an input field based on the selected items TEXT not its Value. Here is my current code:

```
<select name='addEventEventName' style="width:180px" id="addEventEventName" onchange="EventChanged(this)">

                </select>
                <script>                    
                    function EventChanged(changedEvent) 
                    {
                        if (changedEvent.value == "val1" || changedEvent.value == "val2")
                        { $("#jmtest").hide(); }
                        else
                        { $("#jmtest").show(); }
                    }
                </script>
```

**This works perfectly now. But if "val1" and "val2" change in the future it will break.**

I would like to use Sickness (val1) and Holiday (val2) instead. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">                    
function EventChanged(selectEl) 
                    {
  var text = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].text;
  if (text == "Sickness" || text == "Holiday")
     { $("#jmtest").hide(); }
  else
     { $("#jmtest").show(); }
}
</script>
```

Is this it.  I find it it usually bad practice to use Textual labels as the basis for any data decision.  This breaks the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what yr looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="ddlSample" id="ddlSample">
    <option value="1">Sickness</option>
    <option value="2">Holiday</option>
    <option value="3">Sample1</option>
    <option value="4">Sample2</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#ddlSample").change(function(){
    if($(this[this.selectedIndex]).text()=="Sickness" || $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text()=="Holiday")
    {
        alert("Hide input field here.");
        //$("#jmtest").hide();
    }    
    else
    {
        alert("Show input field here.");
        //$("#jmtest").show(); 
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
changedEvent.text== "Sickness" || changedEvent.text== "Holiday"
```

Use this in your if condition. ie change the value attribute of the combo with text attribute.

Comment: Kohli - Hi, that hasn't worked. It now doesn't hide the textbox (#jmtest)

Comment: James, for tis condition to work u must make sure that u r giving value "holiday/sickness" to text attribute to select tag. and use ddlSample.options[ddlSample.selectedIndex].text as text() is not a javascript function. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
changedEvent.options[changedEvent.selectedIndex].text == "Sickness" || changedEvent.options[changedEvent.selectedIndex].text == "Holiday"
```

Comment: i - Hi, that hasn't worked. It now doesn't hide the textbox (#jmtest)

Comment: I modified my answer. I just put value instead of text.